# How do you use accepts_nested_attributes_for when creating new records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I am trying to have one of my models accept nested attributes. The model's name is Tournament, and Tournament has many MapLists. Also worth noting is that the Tournament validates at least one MapList is present. Likewise, MapList validates that tournament_id is present. For a reference, MapList only has 3 attributes: tournament_id, map_order, and map_id. The code, exactly as it appears in Tournament, is:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :map_lists
```

My problem is concerning new Tournament records. For instance, I would like to create a new tournament using code such as:

```
t = Tournament.new({map_lists_attributes: [{map_id: 1, map_order: 1}]}, as: :admin)
```

This code, however, does not work. If I call t.map_lists immediately after instantiating t, I get an empty relation. Obviously, I cannot set tournament_id since I am creating a new record. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any attr_accessible setup for Tournament?

Comment: I do. Do I need to add map_lists to the accessible list?

Comment: cool, I just added an answer about what to do for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attr_assessible will protect against nested-attributes as well... so you'll need to configure like so:

```
class Tournament
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :map_lists
  attr_assessible :map_lists_attributes #and all your others
end
```

Comment: Ok this is getting me closer. Now, new MapLists are being created, but I am still have a problem on save. The tournament_id in MapLists does not seem to be getting set, so the MapList save is failing.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I think the problem comes from the fact that Tournament validates that there is a map_list with map_order 1.